# Displaying x axis labels vertically in ajax barchart

Tags: javascript, css, ajax

to all JS and CSS and AJAX ninjas I am using ajax barchart control to plot data on x axis and y axis but I need the labels on x axis to be displayed vertically instead of horizontally. How can i accomplish this in js, CSS or in code behind (if possible)?

Comment: why dont you change x axis data to y axis data and the same for y axis data

Comment: Did you try the `CSS3 rotate` function? May be [this](http://css-tricks.com/rotated-table-column-headers/) link will be of help.